# app-release.apk not installing after changing package name in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have changed the `package name` and `name` of my application. After changing it, the build `apk_file` was not installing in device. Can any one have solution for this.

> Note: I am using VS-Code.

PFA[image]

Comment: @H ă ɤ í : Please Post error that youf acing while installing app

Comment: Can you try by uninstall existing app from device and try ?

Comment: yes I tried, still not working..

Comment: Have you changed package name in build.gradle file as well or  just in pubspec.yaml  file ?

Comment: @H ă ɤ í : from VS - Code terminal can you run this commad  for run app :
flutter run -v --release  and provide logs.

Answer (score 2):

I have added --no-shrink in command of building apk.

```
flutter build apk --no-shrink
```

Hope it will work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That could be because of the debug and profile manifest files as well as the kotlin file, the package name needs to be changed there too.